# Jersey/Jetty API Handler/Container resends the GET request every 1 min if it does not receive the response within 1 minute

Tags: jersey, ssl-certificate, jetty, embedded-jetty

```
<jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
<jetty.version>9.4.11.v20180605</jetty.version>
```

There is a GET API resource registered with Jersey and I am hitting this API from Postman. In case, the num of records is less and can be fetched within 1 minute, API works fine. But, if the request takes more than 1 minute to process, the Jetty Container closes the previous request Socket and retries by sending same GET request to same API again(no external requests are sent, Jetty is retrying them itself).

FYI : There is no SSL Session being used here.
These are non-Async requests.

Q 1. Any idea why Jetty does that ?

Also, I tried to change the timeouts in ServerFactory like so, but nothing changed the above behaviour :

```
((DefaultServerFactory)startupConfig.getServerFactory()).setIdleThreadTimeout(Duration.minutes(4));
startupConfig.getMetricsFactory().setFrequency(Duration.minutes(4));
```

Q 2. Any idea what settings need to be changed ?

On Production, SSL Sessions are being used and I don't see this problem there.

Q 3. How would SSL Session change this behaviour of resending the new API requests bu Jetty ?

Comment: Don't use 3 year old versions of any http server software. Especially when SSL/TLS is in use.  Upgrade to something more recent, even in the 9.4.x series. (such as 9.4.43.v20210629).  Also, the setting idle-thread-timeout has no real impact on your connection handling.  That would be the http-configuration.setIdleTimeout() that is being used by your connectors.

Comment: Your question is also confusing. Jetty is acting like the server here, right?  If so, it's not resending a request, that's the role of a User-Agent/Client.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I have updated my question. Yes, Jetty is on server side and acting as an API Container. So, for some reason, in order to retry the GET request that did not receive a response after 1 min, it sends the same GET request to same API again and again (after every 1 min). 
Please note that there no SSL Sessions implemented on local.
Also, I tried sending the GET request from Postman and using cURL command, they both show same behavior. So, I concluded that it has something to do with Jetty/Jersey settings.